# If $z$ is an $n$th root of unity, prove that $1/z$ is an $n$th root of unity

Tags: roots

I'm not sure if how I'm going to prove this to be  correct:

Since $z$ is an $n$th root of unity, it means $z^n = 1$

For $1/z$ to be an nth root of unity, lets take it to the power of $n$,

$(1/z)^n$, and so $1/(z^n) = 1/1 = 1$, hence, $1/z$ is an $n$th root of unity ?

Comment: Your answer is right.

Comment: Another way of writing it: $(z^m)^n = (z^n)^m = 1$ for every $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done! That's exactly the most straightforward way to prove it.